# Where should I start if I want to blank all the screens in my classroom apart from mine?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7

I want to create a program (preferably with C#) to lock the keyboard and mouse and show a full screen message saying "Face front" to all the Windows 7 PCs in my classroom apart from the tutors. What frameworks/methods could I use to achieve this?  I envisage a simple program running on my PC with a list of all the student computer names, when I click a button their screen is black and keyboard locked. Any pointers are much appreciated.

It's not a joke, try teaching young teens in a city school with all the distractions of the internet. The PCs are connected to the network and we can have admin access to each PC, IT are happy for me to code it as they don't have the time and as for buying something we don't have the money, our budget was cut 20% this year. Thanks

I'm shocked this has been closed, I'm asking which technology to use, where should I start on a new programming project to help me teach. Wow thanks guys.

Comment: Couldn't you just have everyone turn their computers off if they're not supposed to be using them?

Comment: You might want to stop watching movies where hackers are potrayed doing such things..

Comment: you have to create server-client application if you dont know how  to do its better to hire a programmer

Comment: I'm going to assume you understand that at the *very* least, all computers would have to be connected to the school network and under the control of the school administrator (that is, not a student's private laptop)...

Comment: It is possible, however, my rate is 100 dollars an hour plus travel time and expenses.

Comment: There are a lot of factors in this. And it really depends on how much desktop management software you may already have available installed on your student's computers. This seems like an IT support issue, more than it is a development effort. Probably software exists out there to use.

Comment: Generally speaking, if you want to accomplish such a thing you need to have an application running on each of your target computers.  You also need to severely limit your student's privileges.  They can't be able to download any files or access the task manager, or delete files that they don't have expressed permission to delete, etc.  perform other fundamental things.  The application on your own computer is going to be a tiny tiny amount of the picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before I get to any solutions I'd like to say how appalled I am by some of the question comments.  A school teacher educating our students is trying to find an innovative way keep the attention of his class.  This person should be applauded, not ridiculed.  Grow up people!

Your going to need several pieces to put all of this together.  This is not meant to be suggested as a complete solution but it should get you going in the right direction(s).

First your going to need to think a bit like a hacker.  You'll need an agent app running on all the computers which communicates with the "master" computer/agent (client / server) to know when to lock / unlock.  This could be fraught with all kinds of synchronization issues so be careful about polling intervals, etc.

For the keyboard you'll essentially need what will start out as a keylogger (think hacker stealing your password).  Basically the app will intercept all the keyboard inputs and prevent them from doing anything.  I found another question with some info to get you started ([Capture and send keyboard / mouse input in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112949/capture-and-send-keyboard-mouse-input-in-c-sharp)).  I'm going to stay Completely away from the whole, do you have the right to log keyboard inputs of students here.  I suggest you just throw the text away and not store it anywhere or at the very least consult your school/district lawyer.

My suggestion would be to start out with an app that takes over the whole screen (including the start menu) and is set to stay on top of all other windows.  You can have a text box or something in the middle of the screen with the message you want or just hard code it.

I would suggest resetting the mouse to some corner of the screen whenever it's moved.

Some things to watch out for:

- Make a master key combination that will shut down the app in case it does something you don't expect.
- You WILL end up playing a cat & mouse game with your technically incline students trying to bypass your app.
- Since this is an app running on the machine the task can simply be killed.  Maybe the server should poll the clients to see if they're shutdown.  You might look into a windows service but there are special considerations for a visual window / element in a service (might not be worth the hassle).
- Perhaps a windows service that checks to see if the app is running and launches it if it's been shut down would be a good compromise.
- This will only work on school computers and not students personal machines
- Depending on the antivirus software installed this may get flagged as a keylogger/hacker tool or virus.

Now for the disclaimers / warnings.  You need to figure out the legal parts of this yourself, I'm not making any warranty or legal recommendations here.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, you've given me something to think about.