# Log activity outside application

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse-hook

Maybe again incorrect question but:

I am trying to create an application which will log each user mouse click while running in background.

I managed to log each mouse click type (using `Hook`) but then i got a problem.
I need not only to log each click, but also to know what has been pressed and where.
I need to log second information also that what kind of object is pressed inside some application (`button` or `checkbox` and in which panel if it does exist, also object name), but I don't need to know what are those objects supposed to do.

So, is it possible to do with `global hook` help or are there some libraries which can help to make that?

**EDIT:**
Found that it should be easied it wpf application but but there are more problems with - how to make it log each clicked object, not only inside created wpf.

Comment: Look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112949/capture-and-send-keyboard-mouse-input-in-c-sharp

Comment: Well, thanks of course, but unfortunately, i already reader this statement and as I told in my question, I already created mouse click logging. Now i need to somehow get what kind of object was clicked  and inside what kind of application (Word for example).

Comment: What platform are you using? This is fairly trivial in wpf/silverlight .

Comment: I am using windows forms...  but... is this really simple to wpf? I mean, i tried to find some information, but using a global hook it the better option I get at this monent... :( Honeslty i didn't even thinked about wpf

Comment: Well... wpf has an easy acces to elements but as i understand, it is possible to get only elements inside application, but not global at all, so ... this don't make any sense